# Sharepoint List Column Type

Tags: list

I have a sharepoint "Single line of text" column with data in it and I want to change it to a Choice field where the choices being the unique values present in the single line of text column. IS it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Updating a column type is not possible in SharePoint,  a better way would be to create a new column of "Choice" type and write a workflow or powershell script to copy over data from one column to another column.

Make sure that your choice field contains all the possible values from your original column.

Hope this answers your query.